# Force delete on table that uses optimistic locking with version number

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Dynamo table that uses optimistic locking via the `DynamoDBVersionAttribute` to ensure that only one worker at a time has a document reserved. However, when I want to clean up a document, the delete throws a `ConditionalCheckFailedException` when I don't set the version in the `DynamoDBMapper`.

At that point, I don't care what version the document is, and I want to delete it no matter what version it is. Is there a way to force the delete without worrying about the version? I want to overcome the exception without having to query Dynamo for the document.

Answer (score 4):

You can delete the item by specifying the SaveBehaviour as CLOBBER without worrying about the version.

```
DynamoDBMapper mapper;
mapper.delete(object, new DynamoDBMapperConfig(DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.CLOBBER)
```

Comment: Directly constructing the config has been deprecated in favor of using the builder:

```DynamoDBMapperConfig.builder().withSaveBehavior(DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.CLOBBER).build()```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete a Dynamo item using `DynamoMapper` unless you set the version field to the correct version; thus, if you want to avoid make a get request to find the document before deleting it, you have to use the `deleteItem` method on the Dynamo client directly.

Comment: this is not correct. per the above answer setting the save mode to CLOBBER will ignore version numbers